# Test and log terminal output

Tags: bash, if-statement, output, conditional-operator

I am using the following command line in order to send command to my device controller thru bluetoothctl tool.

```
#!/bin/sh
{ sleep 1 && echo -e 'power on \n' && sleep 1;} | bluetoothctl
```

Which returns in the terminal :

```
root@snp:~# ./bt.sh 
[NEW] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 snp [default]
[NEW] Device 98:0D:2E:E5:14:81 HTC
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 Powered: yes
[DEL] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 snp [default]
```

I would like to reduce and manage the number of messages returned. Basically, I want to display on screen and store in a log file :

```
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 Powered: yes
```

I enter

```
{ sleep 1 && echo -e 'power on \n' && sleep 1;} | bluetoothctl | grep -E "Changing|[CHG]" 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

But I obtain,

```
root@snp:~# ./bt.sh 
[NEW] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 snp [default]
[NEW] Device 01:02:03:04:05:C3 HTC 
Changing power on succeeded
[DEL] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 snp [default]
```

Where is my fault ?

In addition, is it possible to test if Powered = yes or not thru a conditional test, and all stuff do in the same line ?

### --------------------------------

Edit n°1 :

Indeed, the status messages are not directed to standard error, 2>&1 was useless.

However, I tried your proposition by means of :

```
{ sleep 1 && echo -e 'power on \n' && sleep 1;} | bluetoothctl | grep -E 'Changing|\[CHG]'
```

which always returns

```
root@snp:~# ./bt.sh 
Changing power on succeeded
```

Instead of

```
root@snp:~# ./bt.sh 
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 01:02:03:04:05:C3 Powered: yes
```

Comment: Does `bluetoothctl` write to STDOUT or STDERR?

Comment: bluetoothctl write to STDOUT

Answer (score 1):

The regex `[CHG]` is a character class which matches any one of `C`, `H`, or `G`.  If you want to match an opening square bracket literally, you have to escape it.

```
grep -E 'Changing|\[CHG]'
```

In addition, you might want to check whether the status messages are being directed to standard error.  If so, try

```
... | bluetoothctl 2>&1 | grep ...
```

The `grep 2>&1` redirection you have does not seem to serve any useful purpose.